# update with script pre-installed in elasticsearch

Tags: elastic4s

I want to use scripts in the way[ https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-groovy-scripts-without-dynamic-scripting ] for security purpose.

I tried this in `sense`(chrome plugin) and it works well. Wondering how to achieve this in elastic4s.

For example, I want to remove a field from doc, and code like this:

```
def replaceWithId(alarmId: String, fieldName: String, fieldValue: Map[String, Any]) = {
client.execute {
  update id alarmId in IndexType script """{"file":"removeOperationField"}"""

}}
```

but it failed.

Comment: Is your file actually called "removeOperationField" or "removeOperationField.groovy" or something ?

Comment: file name is removeOperationField, since its type is groovy we don't have to declare lang.

Comment: java client can do this by `client.prepareUpdate("index", "type", "id")
      .setScript("removeIpField", ScriptService.ScriptType.FILE)
      .get `

Comment: Yep I know you don't need to declare the language, but just wanted to make sure you hadn't given the file a file extension when you saved it.

Comment: full file name is "removeOperationField.groovy", file extension doesn't matter(I tried this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the script type, rather than including it in the json explicitly, eg:

```
def replaceWithId(alarmId: String) = {
  client.execute {
    update id alarmId in IndexType script("scriptname", ScriptType.File)
  }
}
```

Comment: After upgraded to elastic4s 1.6.0, I finally saw this function. I was using 1.3.3 where script(string) cannot specify script type.